# Let $ f: \mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ be $\mathcal C^\infty$ with $ f'(x) = f(1-x)$ for all $x$. Given $ f(0)=1$. Find $ f(1)$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $ f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be an infinitely differentiable
> function such that $$ f'(x) = f(1-x)$$ for all $x$. Given $ f(0)=1$,
> find $ f(1)$.

I tried to solve the differential equation $ f'(x) = f(1-x)$ , but I am not able to do .

Comment: `\to` makes a function arrow.

Comment: "I looked for the meaning of the infinitely differentiable function and wiki says it is the smoothness (which I didn't understand)" -- It just means it is of class $C^{\infty}$, i.e. differentiable infinitely many times.

Comment: oh!, Thank you @EeveeTrainer, I was confused by the term smoothness.

Answer (score 8):

Since $f'(x)=f(1-x)$, differentiating gives $f''(x)=-f'(1-x)$. But by the first equation, $f'(1-x)=f(x)$, so that $f''(x)=-f(x)$. Thus, $f(x)=C_1\cos x+C_2\sin x$. Can you finish?

Comment: so @Kenta S sir, I am not able to understand how did you get the functional equation as $f(x)=C_1\cos x+C_2\sin x$ for $f''(x)=-f(x),if possible please give a detailed proof.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Homogeneous_equation_with_constant_coefficients

Comment: Without diff eq, from calculus, we know that if $f(x)=cos(x)$, then $f''(x)=-cos(x)=-f''(x)$ and it is the same with $g(x)=sin(x)$, Now, this doesn't give you ALL functions, but you can form a linear combination using constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ to give you the form @KentaS states.  Now you can just use your initial condition.